# SQL Query to join multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have 4 tables that I need to connect in order to get the reports that I need. But I'm confused on how to write the query. Below are the sample of the tables:

**Client Table**

```
client_id  |  client_name  |  con_id
----------:|:-------------:|:-------
    1      |     ABC       |  1
    2      |     DEF       |  1
    3      |     GHI       |  2
```

**Consultant**

```
con_id  |  con_name
-------:|:---------
   1    |    Ani
   2    |   Robby
```

**Perm**

```
pid  |  client_id  |  date
----:|:-----------:|:-----------
 1   |      1      |  2014-08-09
 2   |      1      |  2014-03-02
 3   |      2      |  2014-03-02
```

**Temp**

```
tid  |  client_id  |  date
----:|:-----------:|:-----------
 1   |     2       |  2013-02-09
 2   |     3       |  2011-03-02
 3   |     3       |  2012-04-02
```

The end result of the report that I want to show is something like this:

```
client_id  |  client_name  |  perm(COUNT)  |  temp(COUNT)  |  con_name
----------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|:---------
    1      |       ABC     |       2       |         0     |    Ani
    2      |       DEF     |       1       |         1     |    Ani
    3      |       GHI     |       0       |         2     |    Robby
```

I'm trying to use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but I don't get the result that I want. Can anyone help me to figure out the query?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use the inner join & left outer join. The column that I'm confused to obtain the data is on column Perm & Temp.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to use a left outer join for this query.  The client_id in both PERM AND TEMP can be used for the join onto the the client table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple outer join query with count and group by,just join your `client` table with the related ones and count only the distinct associations

```
select 
c.client_id,
c.client_name,
count(distinct p.pid) perm_count,
count(distinct t.tid) temp_count,
cn.con_name
from client c
left join Consultant cn on(c.con_id = cn.con_id)
left join Perm p on(c.client_id = p.client_id)
left join `Temp` t on(c.client_id = t.client_id)
group by c.client_id
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42e24e/5)

Answer (score 0):

You should connect all table by joinig all query in one sql.See the link http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/using-a-where-cluase-to-join-two-tables-related-by-a-single-column-primary-key-or-foriegn-key-pair.php

Comment: the part that I'm confused is the column 'perm' & 'temp'

Comment: Whats exactly you want first write.Then i can provide solution for that.

Comment: Hi @rani dubey, you can refer to the last table on my question. That is the end report that I need to produce.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.client_id as client_id, a.client_name as client_name,
                a.con_id as client_con_id,
                b.con_id as con_id,
                b.con_name as con_name,
                c.pid as perm_id,
                c.client_id as perm_client_id
                c.date as perm_date
                d.tid as temp_id,
                d.client_id as tem_client_id
```

....Anthing that you want to select ....

```
                from client_table a 
                Inner join Consultant_table b on a.client_con_id = b.con_id
                Inner join perm_table c on a.client_id= c.perm_client_id
                Inner join Temp_table d on....
```

Comment: how bout the count for column temp & perm?

Comment: same logic, 
Select d.perm(COUNT) as perm_count, d.temp(count) as temp_count
 inner join d on d.con_name = b.con_name